# A reason this function is unselecting radio buttons too?

Tags: javascript, html

So I am using this function to make it so that only one of my checkboxes can be selected at a time.

```
function checkOnly(stayChecked) {
                with (document.drinkList) {
                    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                        if (elements[i].checked == true && elements[i].name != stayChecked.name) {
                            elements[i].checked = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This code works, but, after you check a checkbox, all radio buttons become unselected in my form. Is there any way I can fix this by using the current code? Thanks.

Comment: Check the `.tagName` property to make sure it's not a radio button.

Comment: You should use [something other than `with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radiobuttons also have a `checked` property, so since you are iterating over all your elements, the radiobuttons become deselected too. You could circumvent this by checking the `tagName` property of the element, so you can check if it is a checkbox.

But actually you shouldn't have to. Don't write a script to allow only one checkbox to be checked. Use radiobuttons instead. Radiobuttons are the controls to use if you can only select one options, while checkboxes are for multiple options. You are now basically scripting checkboxes to behave like radiobuttons, which is error-prone and not user-friendly, since it goes against expectations.

Anyway, if you want to do that, you can do so using the following snippet. It doesn't use jQuery, although it does use some Javascript that is only available in the more recent browsers. 
After loading the DOM, it binds a click event to checkboxes only. Clicking such a checkbox would deselect all others. Also you cannot deselect the checkbox itself by clicking it again. This way, the behaviour is pretty much like a radiobutton. So, yes, you can. But, no, you shouldn't. :)

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  
  // Get all checkboxes and bind a click event handler to them
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', function(){

      // When clicked, iterate over the checkboxes again. 
      // If the iterated box is not the clicked one, unselect it.
      for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i] != this) {
          checkboxes[i].checked = false;
        }
      }

      // If the one that was clicked in unselected, reselect it.
      if (this.checked == false) {
         this.checked = true;
      }  
      
    });
    
  }
  
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">Choice 1<br>
<input type="checkbox">Choice 2<br>
<input type="checkbox">Choice 3<br>
<input type="checkbox">Choice 4<br>
<input type="checkbox">Choice 5<br>
<input type="checkbox">Choice 6<br>
```

Comment: I emailed my professor about that, but she insists that I use radio buttons for one thing, and then checkboxes for another. Idk why she wants to make it 10x more difficult.

Comment: Maybe she wants a multi-select for the other choice.. Or maybe she wants to show why it is better to use radiobuttons. Are maybe she's silly, it happens sometimes. Anyway, as long as *you* know the difference. ;-)

Comment: She has us using Radio Buttons for choices of size (small, medium, large) and then checkboxes for 3 ice cream flavors, which also can only have one selected. That's why I am confused.

Comment: You sure? I'd like to combine flavors. I'll have a large one with chocolate, coconut and almond. Of course I can't read the assignment, but it still makes sense that that question is intended as multi-select. Anyway, I've provided a script that shows you how to do it if you want to, but I'd seriously reconsider. ;-)

Comment: Haha, it's just for one sundae, but I see where you are coming from :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're iterating through all the elements in the form, not just the elements in your checkbox group, so you're catching the one checkbox that you've just checked, leaving it untouched, and clearing every other element you iterate through.

Are you using jQuery at all? You could select elements with much higher granularity fairly easily, be sure you're just getting the checkboxes in the group you've fired the function from and ensure you're only iterating over those.

I'm also wondering, if you're making checkboxes behave like radio buttons, why aren't you using radio buttons?

Another option would be to confirm the type of the element you're selecting before you clear it.

```
type == "checkbox"
```

Then only clear elements of type == "checkbox"

elements[i].checked == true && elements[i].name != stayChecked.name && elements[i].type == "checkbox"

Comment: No this is for a javascript class of mine. Haven't touched jQuery, but I see it a lot. And we have to use radio and checkboxes, but the checkboxes have to act like radio buttons. Idk, my professor has gone mad.